# Trying to open Windows Powershell. Access to memory restricted

Tags: windows, powershell

I recently upgraded my pc to Windows 10 and for the most part everything seemed to be working fine. Powershell was working fine until I opened up a shell and got this error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetProviderPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ResolveDriveQualifiedPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProvider& providerInstance)
   at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedMonadPathsFromMonadPath(String path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProviderContext context, CmdletProvider& providerInstance)
   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.SetLocation(String path, CmdletProviderContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.SetSessionStateDrive(ExecutionContext context, Boolean setLocation)
   at System.Management.Automation.AutomationEngine..ctor(PSHost hostInterface, RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration, InitialSessionState iss)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace.DoOpenHelper()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.CoreOpen(Boolean syncCall)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.OpenConsoleRunspace(Runspace runspace, Boolean staMode)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.DoCreateRunspace(String initialCommand, Boolean skipProfiles, Boolean staMode, Boolean importSystemModules, Collection`1 initialCommandArgs)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.CreateRunspace(Object runspaceCreationArgs)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

causing the prompt to show me a "Windows PowerShell has stopped working" popup. I tried running the shell as an admin and restarting my computer, waiting for the memory in RAM to decay. Is there an easy fix, such as reinstalling a framework, or would I need to buy a new RAM chip for my machine?

Machine specs:

- Lenovo Yoga 13 (1st gen)
- 8GB RAM (originally came with 4, I upgraded)
- 104 GB Storage
- Intel core i5-3337U @ 1.80 GHz
- 64 bit

**UPDATE**
Going to the file location, I was able to open PowerShell(x86) with no problems. I can execute commands but I'd prefer to solve the regular PowerShell if possible.

Comment: If you open powershell with `-noprofile` does it work? You have custom scripts loading with PowerShell that are maybe no longer compatible

Comment: @Matt No, I tried that and get the same result.

Comment: If it's not strange modules/legacy code in your profile.. and Googling this returns similar examples of this error triggered by other applications, maybe try asking this question in the Server Fault site?

Comment: Create a new user and login to the computer with the new user.  Try opening PowerShell.  If that works the problem is likely your user profile.  An online search will direct you to re-creating your profile.  Additionally, you may want to run a Memory Test.